# How to use SearchView with LiveData and ViewModel in Room

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, searchview

i want to use SearchView for search some element in room db and i have a problem with this because i cant use getFilter in RecyclerViewAdapter because i have ViewModel maybe whoes know how to combine all of this element in one project.
I search one way use Transormations.switchMap. But I couldn’t connect them.

> **ProductViewModel**

```
class ProductViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val repository: ProductRepository

    val allProducts: LiveData<List<ProductEntity>>
    private val searchStringLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()

    init {
        val productDao = ProductsDB.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).productDao()
        repository = ProductRepository(productDao)
        allProducts = repository.allProducts
        searchStringLiveData.value = ""
    }

    fun insert(productEntity: ProductEntity) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.insert(productEntity)
    }


    val products = Transformations.switchMap(searchStringLiveData) { string ->
        repository.getAllListByName(string)

    }

    fun searchNameChanged(name: String) {
        searchStringLiveData.value = name
    }



}
```

> **ProductDao**

```
interface ProductDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insertProduct(productEntity: ProductEntity)

    @Query("SELECT * from products")
    fun getListAllProducts(): LiveData<List<ProductEntity>>


    @Query("DELETE FROM products")
    suspend fun deleteAll()

    @Query("SELECT * FROM products where product_name_ent LIKE :name or LOWER(product_name_ent) like LOWER(:name)")
    fun  getListAllByName(name: String):LiveData<List<String>>

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **ProductDao**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM products where product_name_ent LIKE :name or LOWER(product_name_ent) like LOWER(:name)")
            fun  getListAllByName(name: String):LiveData<List<ProductEntity>>
```

This Method in your dao should return `LiveData<List<ProductEntity>>` and not `LiveData<List<String>>`, because this query selects **everything** (*) from the entity and **not** a specific column.

it is similar to  (`@Query("SELECT * from products") fun getListAllProducts():LiveData<List<ProductEntity>>`)

> **ProductViewModel**

```
    class ProductViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
        private val repository: ProductRepository
        init {
            val productDao = ProductsDB.getDatabase(
                application,
                viewModelScope
            ).productDao()
            repository = ProductRepository(productDao)
        }


        private val searchStringLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>("") //we can add initial value directly in the constructor
        val allProducts: LiveData<List<ProductEntity>>=Transformations.switchMap(searchStringLiveData)
        {
            string->
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(string)) {
                repository.allProducts()
            } else {
                repository.allProductsByName(string)
            }
        }


        fun insert(productEntity: ProductEntity) = viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.insert(productEntity)
        }

        fun searchNameChanged(name: String) {
            searchStringLiveData.value = name
        }


    }
```

> **Repository**

...with the other method that you have, add the following:

```
fun allProducts():LiveData<List<ProductEntity>>=productDao.getListAllProducts()
fun allProductsByNames(name:String):LiveData<List<ProductEntity>>=productDao.getListAllByName(name)
```

> **In Your Activity Or Fragment Where you have the recyclerview adapter**

inside onCreate() (if it is an activity)

```
viewModel.allProducts.observe(this,Observer{products->
//populate your recyclerview here
})
```

or

```
onActivityCreated(if it is a fragment)
       viewModel.allProducts.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,Observer{products->
    //populate your recyclerview here
    })
```

Now set a listener to the searchView, everytime the user submit the query , call `viewModel.searchNameChanged(// pass the new value)`

Hope this helps

Regards,

Comment: wow thank u so mutch, easy and smart way