# Searchview doesn't work, but shows no errors

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, searchview

i don't know why my SearchView doesn't work. It shows no errors, it just don't search. Here my code. I am using MVVM-Pattern and LiveData. Maybe someone knows why it doesn't work.
I've followed a Tutorial: [How to use SearchView with LiveData and ViewModel in Room](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59737021/how-to-use-searchview-with-livedata-and-viewmodel-in-room)
Thanks in advance. :)

MY DAO:

```
@Dao
```

interface VorratsDao {

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)        //Insert, aber bei vorhandenem Objekt wird es geupdatet
suspend fun upsertVorrat(produkt: ProduktVorrat)        //suspend fun, welche für Corountines benötigt wird

@Delete
suspend fun deleteVorrat(produkt: ProduktVorrat)        // Löschen eines einzelnen Produktes

@Delete
suspend fun deleteAllVorrat(list : List<ProduktVorrat>) // Löschen der ganzen Liste

@Query("SELECT * FROM vorrat_produkt")              //SQL-Anweisung um ganze Tabelle zu erhalten
fun getAllProdukteVorratsliste() : LiveData<List<ProduktVorrat>>

@Query("SELECT * FROM vorrat_produkt WHERE vprodukt_name LIKE :searchQuery")
fun getProduktbyName(searchQuery: String) : LiveData<List<ProduktVorrat>>
```

}

MY Repository:

```
 suspend fun upsertVorrat(produkt: ProduktVorrat) = db.getVorratsDao().upsertVorrat(produkt)

suspend fun deleteVorrat(produkt: ProduktVorrat) = db.getVorratsDao().deleteVorrat(produkt)

suspend fun deleteAllVorrat(list : List<ProduktVorrat>) = db.getVorratsDao().deleteAllVorrat(list)

fun getAllProdukteVorratsliste() : LiveData<List<ProduktVorrat>> = db.getVorratsDao().getAllProdukteVorratsliste()

fun getProduktByName(searchQuery : String) : LiveData<List<ProduktVorrat>> =db.getVorratsDao().getProduktbyName(searchQuery)
```

MY Viewmodel:

```
fun getAllProdukteVorratsliste() = repository.getAllProdukteVorratsliste()

    fun getProduktByName(searchQuery: String) = repository.getProduktByName(searchQuery)`

   private val searchStringLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>("")
    val allProducts: LiveData<List<ProduktVorrat>> = Transformations.switchMap(searchStringLiveData)
{
    string->
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(string)) {
        getAllProdukteVorratsliste()
    } else {
        getProduktByName(string)
    }
}

    fun searchNameChanged(name: String) {
        searchStringLiveData.value = name
    }
```

MY Activity:

```
class VorratslisteActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

val CHANNEL_ID = "channelID"
val CHANNEL_NAME = "channelName"
val NOTIFICATION_ID = 0

lateinit var binding: ActivityVorratslisteBinding


@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityVorratslisteBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    createNotificationChannel()

val database = EinkaufDatenbank(this)        //Erstellen der Datenbank
    val repository = Repository(database)               //Erstellen des Repositorys
    val factory = ViewModelFactory(repository)          //Erstellen der Viewmodelfactory



    val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(ViewModel::class.java)         //Erstllen des Viewmodels


    val adapter = ProduktVorratAdapter(listOf(), viewModel)    

binding.rvEinkaeufeListe.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    binding.rvEinkaeufeListe.adapter = adapter      //adapter zuweisen

binding.searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(p0: String?): Boolean {
            if(p0 != null) {
                viewModel.searchNameChanged(p0)
            }
            return true
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(p0: String?): Boolean {
            if(p0 != null) {
                viewModel.searchNameChanged(p0)
            }
            return true
        }


    })
```

Comment: did you get the result from live data while typing a keyword? could you debug that result?

Comment: no i don't think so. if i debug it just shows me the "p0" string

Comment: val allProducts: LiveData<List<ProduktVorrat>>  
This variable is never used tho ..

Comment: where is your observer?.```viewModel.allProducts.observe(this,Observer{products->
//populate your recyclerview here
})```

Comment: ` viewModel.allProducts.observe(this, Observer { 
            adapter.items = it
        })`
Like this?

Comment: did you solve it?. I think you know the function of the observer it will listen to all allproducts live data. whenever we type in a search. You can look at this article.https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-live-data-data-binding#3

Comment: Its working! Thank you very much!